# pefle: how to handle unicode filename

Tags: python, unicode

It say's that pefile python module v1.2.8 is able to handle unicode characters.
I have 1.2.10 installed, but still, I encountered exceptions when passing 
files with Japanesse filename(s). How will I pass PE files with filename having UnicodeCharacters?

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import pefile
pe = pefile.PE(str("c:/temp/じゃｙそｎ.exe").decode('utf-8'))
```

Snippet code above gives this exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 37-194: ordinal 
not in range(128)
```

How should I handle this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

str() isn't unicode().

Try using a unicode bytestring (notice the 'u' before the ".:

```
pe = pefile.PE(u"c:/temp/じゃｙそｎ.exe"))
```

And then read this:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Worth noting that Py3k defaults string objects to Unicode so if you are working with it in future, you won't need to worry about this.